# I've embedded my ViewController in a Tab Bar Controller and now my coreDataStack.managedContext fails

Tags: core-data, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

My starting app works fine, however now I want to start adding extra functionality so I’ve embedded the initial view (which was already in a Navigation Controller) in a Tab Bar Controller.  This when it stops working.

I believe it’s something to do with the way I’ve set managedContext in my AppDelegate file.  You’ll see in my code sample below I’ve changed the setup from UINavigationController and .topViewController to UITabBarController and .selectedViewController but when the code executes it immediately fails and shows the error in the ViewController.swift class file for the initial view.

// **** Sample code from ViewController:

```
do {
  let results = try managedContext.fetch(LocationFetch)    <—— Thread 1: Fatal error: …
  if results.count > 0 {
    // Fido found, use Fido
    currentLocation = results.first
  } else {
```

// **** Sample code from the AppDelegate file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
guard let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
    let viewController = navController.selectedViewController as? ViewController else {
        return true
}

viewController.managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
return true
```

}

I don't understand enough about Swift to solve this on my own so any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.  I've looked in many places but I don't have the experience to figure this out.

Comment: Can you add the full error message to your question?  Also, does your `managedContext` assignment actually execute and, if so, what value does it set?

Comment: This was the full error message: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value)

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from elsewhere (thank you S.Gerrard), I was correct about the issue being in the AppDelegate and related to the change of view, although I came close to a solution I didn’t yet have the experience to piece it altogether correctly...

As the root controller was no longer a UINavigationController, so the navController is nil, and the viewController.managedContext is never assigned.

I needed to replace the “if block” with something which starts by getting the tab controller, then gets the navigation controller from it’s first tab (viewControllers?[0]), then gets the view controller from that and does the assignment:

if
      let tabController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
      let navController = tabController.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController,
      let viewController = navController.topViewController as? ViewController
    {
      viewController.managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
    }